# Filter on a specific property from code using angularjs built-in filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

How can we filter based on a specific property for the built-in filter, from code?
I know how to do it from markup -

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users | filter:{status:status}">{{user.name}}</li>
```

This seems to be a particular problem when the property name is a variable. I've recreated the problem in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n925b20L/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) if you need to construct an object with a dynamic key stored in variable:

```
$scope.$watch('status', function(){
    var filter = {};
    filter[$scope.filterby.val] = $scope.status;
    $scope.filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.users, filter);
    console.log($scope.filtered);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/n925b20L/2/